# is it possible to manage Multiple tables using a single model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any way to use one single model for different tables if all of
the tables have the same fields and attributes? I have first table with 3 millions of records. so I'm thinking to make another table like 'tablename_2' to make fast querying in future.

I would like to use existing model ,but based on some conditions it should decide which table need to be accessed.

I want to know whether this is possible?

Comment: Pretty odd requirement. Maybe it's better to have one table? Anyways you have many tables with idential structure.

Comment: Very odd architecture. Could you be more specific and provide some example?

Comment: You’re most likely better off using controllers and helpers to save to different tables using separate models instead of trying to construct custom models representing multiple tables. By my experience ActiveRecord does not handle such situation very well.

Comment: Having multiple tables will probably make your searches more complex in logic, throwing away any advantage you could have in relation to a single table with many records.

Comment: anything is possible, but this seems like a Bad Idea(tm). if you find yourself needing multiple tables to represent a single model it sounds like concerns are not being isolated effectively.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try something like this:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.within_table(name)
    begin
      previous_table_name = self.table_name
      self.table_name = name if name.present?
      yield if block_given?

    ensure
      self.table_name = previous_table_name
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

And call it with this:

```
# This register will be created in 'examples' table (default table name)
Example.create! attribute: 'value'

# Las element from 'examples' table
Example.last

Example.within_table 'examples_copy' do
  # This one will be created in 'examples_copy' table
  Example.create! attribute: 'value'
  # Last register of 'examples_copy' table
  Example.last
end
```

Please, bear in mind that this code is probably **not thread safe**, and should be used carefully. Also, is not a good idea to split your model content between different tables. You should use different models, or [single table inheritange](https://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's called **horizontal database scaling** or scaling *out* whereby a large database is split into smaller sets to handle load. **Vertical scaling** or scaling *up* is done by increasing hardware.

There are two options for scaling *out*:

**1. Read replicas**

These are usually used for apps with a high read/write ratio. Think news websites where articles written by a few writers can be consumed by millions around the world. Essentially you have one master database handling all writes which are then replicated onto slave databases that handle read operations.

**2. Database sharding**

Databases can be split either by rows, by tables, by feature, by geography, by client, or by any other measure. No data is shared between databases. You would use this architecture if there are clear boundaries that can be drawn between your data i.e you have Saas customers in different countries and there's no chance that they would need data from another country.

Read more here https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Shard_(database_architecture)

This question has more to do with your database architecture than Rails however. If I were in your shoes I'd focus on denormalization, indexing, query optimization, and vertical scaling before I'd consider scaling it out.

3 million records should not a problem for postgreSQL, but if you're growing ^100% month on month it would be prudent to start baking in some scalability into your database.